# Change pagination image to text in Joomla 3

Tags: joomla-3.x

I need the >> to be next and << to be previous, where can I change that?
please see attached for clarity.[image]

I did inspect but still cannot find it. Here is the rendering code but I can't find where to edit the buttons.                                                       `function pagination_list_render($list) {
    // Initialize variables
    $html = '';

```
//if ($list['start']['active']==1)   $html .= $list['start']['data'];
if ($list['previous']['active']==1) $html .= $list['previous']['data'];

//foreach ($list['pages'] as $page) {
//  $html .= $page['data'];
//}

if ($list['next']['active']==1) $html .= $list['next']['data'];
//if ($list['end']['active']==1)  $html .= $list['end']['data'];

$html .= "</ul>";

return $html;
```

}` 
Thank you

Comment: Have you inspected the element using dev tools or firebug? This will give you the location. Or post a link to your site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the pagination in your active template under */templates/template_name/html/pagination.php*, if there's no file just copy the one in protostar and edit it as you like.